# Automatic OTP verification for a specific number in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In order to set the otp automatically I set this property

```
activationCode.textContentType = UITextContentTypeOneTimeCode;
```

but this shows any sms starting with "code:", I want it to show this only for an specific number, not for any number.

Comment: For otp use UITextContentTypeOneTimeCode

Comment: @RajeshKumarR thanks. I had typo mistake.

Comment: I do not think that is possible. Is that really an issue for you? Do you expect multiple sms from other senders to come in while your app is waiting for your message?

Comment: @luk2302 exactly. I think this might happen.